# using CGRectIntersectsRect for updating score of my game

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage

I am trying to update my score using `CGRectIntersectsRect` and I want to increment in my score every time two images collide with each other. But, my score does not show periodicity some times it increases by one unit but it increases randomly when two UIimages collide with higher speed. Here is my code:

```
-(void)Collision{

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Ball.frame, Player.frame)) {

    PlayerScoreNumber = PlayerScoreNumber + 1;
    PlayerScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", PlayerScoreNumber];

    Y = arc4random() %5;
    Y = 0-Y;

}
```

The two `UIImages` are 'ball' and 'racket' , I want to increment in my score every time the ball strikes the racket. Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are counting the same collision twice (or more) and so you are going to have to keep *state* about the collision and remember when you've already seen the current collision:

Create a new instance variable in your implementation file, something like:

```
@interface MyClass ()
{
    BOOL _ballCollidedWithPlayer;
}
```

and manage the state like this:

```
-(void)Collision{

    BOOL collided = CGRectIntersectsRect(Ball.frame, Player.frame);
    if (collided) {
        if (_ballCollidedWithPlayer)
            return;    // Nothing to do; we already know about this collision

        PlayerScoreNumber = PlayerScoreNumber + 1;
        PlayerScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", PlayerScoreNumber];

        Y = arc4random() %5;
        Y = 0-Y;
    }
    _ballCollidedWithPlayer = collided;
}
```